# Specify Visual Format Language within Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

Is it possible to specify a constraint using Visual Format Language from within the Interface Builder and have it reflected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bringo said, it's designed for programmatically defining constraints. But before using it, I'd suggest looking at the new `NSLayoutAnchor` based method for programmatically setting up constraints. See [Layout Anchors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) in Apples documentation. I've found anchors to be a simple API to use.

Comment: ...Although layout anchors are only available in iOS >= 9. I got bitten by this recently when developing a client app that supports iOS 8 and later. The first time I tried to run it under iOS 8, I crashed. APIs that only work on the latest and greatest OS are not that useful in real world apps that have to support customers using a variety of OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

No, Interface Builder provides you with tools to specify your constraints using a GUI.

The visual format language is purely intended for making constraints in code easier.

Comment: Can this be exposed via IBInspectable?